# How to show the Text instead of value in Kendo combobox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Combobox in a View that will have multiple uses (Create and Edit).

It works fine when I filtered, but I'm doing the Edit function, when I load the page I send the value to View. The combox shows the Id sent, but I want to show the text.

```
<div class="form-group" id="frmg_Billing.cityId">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BillingCityId, new { @class = "col-sm-4 col-md-6 col-lg-5 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.BillingCityId)
            .Name("BillingCityId")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("Id")
            .Placeholder("Ciudad")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: auto;" })
            .MinLength(5)
            .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetCities", "Common")
                        .Data("filterCities");
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true);
            })
            .AutoBind(false)
        )
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function filterCities() {
        return {
            cityFilter: $("#BillingCityId").data("kendoComboBox").input.val()
        };
    }
</script>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
public ActionResult GetCities(string cityFilter)
{
    _cityBLL = new CityBLL();
    var result = _cityBLL.getCities(cityFilter).Select(city => new CityModel
    {
        Id = city.CODCIU_CIU,
        Name = city.NOMCIU_CIU,
        ParentStateId = city.CODEST_CIU
    });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Post your `GetCities` action.

Comment: By the way, your javascript code needs to be inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Yes, it is inside in a <script> tag.

Comment: I updated the cuestion to post the code. This method I use to filter the cities by text. It works fine when I'm creating a new record (I can search and select the city). But I'm doing the Edit function (When the View is loading I send the value/Id from the database). But I want to show the text.

Comment: I updated your question, and put the function inside a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Are you sure `NOMCIU_CIU` has the city names, and not the Ids? Everything looks ok in your code.